# Module 'ngMockE2E' is not available! AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpbackend, ngmocke2e

Getting the following error in my browser:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sayHiApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMockE2E due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMockE2E' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/nomod?p0=ngMockE2E
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1611:17
    at ensure (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1535:38)
    at module (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1609:14)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3717:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
    at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3711:5)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3718:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngMockE2E&p1=Error…ngular%2Fangular.js%3A3718%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3745:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
    at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3711:5)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3718:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
    at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3711:5)
    at createInjector (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3651:11)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=sayHiApp&p1=Error%…F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3651%3A11) angular.js:78
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('sayHiApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMockE2E',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .run(function($httpBackend) {

    var name = '';

    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/name').respond(function(method, url, data) {
      name = angular.fromJson(data);
      return [200, name, {}];
    });

    $httpBackend.whenGET('/name').respond(name);

  });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you loading `angular-mocks.js` script file?

Comment: Ho oh... I think that's the issue.. let me quickly bower install

Comment: Yep that was the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `angular.mocks.js` file consists of a number of modules helpful in mocking and testing. The most used ones are `ngMock`, `ngMockE2E` which provide the mocks for some of the most used components such as `$timeout, $rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend` ($httpBackend is part of ngMockE2E).

In order to use any of these modules as dependecy you need to load `angular.mocks.js`. Just add this script in your html file to remove the `[$injector:modulerr]` which is an error caused when the module added as dependency is not found or its file has not been loaded

Answer (score 2):

I only add to use $httpBackend, so only 'ngMocksE2E' module was necessary, so I did:

```
import angular from 'angular';
// it exports moduleName that is 'ngMockE2E'
import ngMockE2EModuleName from 'angular-mocks/ngMocksE2E.js';

export default angular.module('app', [ngMockE2EModuleName]);
```